# fnmatch does not work with variables but with static strings

Tags: python, regex, linux, python-2.7

The following code does not find any of the patterns defined in the file `patterns`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import fnmatch

patternFile = open('patterns', 'r')
patterns = patternFile.readlines()
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    for pattern in patterns:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern):
            print "FOUND!"
```

My `pattern` file looks like

```
*test
foo
```

The following modified code with a static pattern string works. As expected, a file named `foofile` could be found.

```
patternFile = open('patterns', 'r')
patterns = patternFile.readlines()
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*test'):
        print "FOUND!"
```

Does anybody know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines` includes newline character `\n` at the end of each line, you need to do:

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern.strip('\n\r'):
```